# "I got the feeling that..."

Tags: translation, expressions

How can I express that in Chinese?
Examples:

- I got a feeling that your English is better than my Chinese.
- I got a feeling that tonight is going to be a good night.
- I got a bad feeling about this.
- I got a feeling that they are going to turn down our proposal.

etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Umm it's worth noting that (most of the time) "I got a" is actually incorrect English. "I got a feeling that tonight is going to be a good night" should be `"I have the feeling that tonight is going to be a good night"`, "I got a bad feeling about this" should be `"I have a bad feeling about this"`, and "I got a feeling that they are going to turn down our proposal" should be `"I have the feeling that they are going to turn down our proposal"`. So the sentiment is actually incorrect.

Comment: `我觉得` or `我感觉` ...

Comment: @ming This is actually okay as colloquial English, like a contraction of 'I've got...'  Also, about the article, 'a' or 'the' are both fine.  Anyway it's perfectly clear what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @neubau 'colloquial' is pretty much 'widely accepted incorrect usage' :) Yes, it's understood, but no, it's still wrong. The reason I switch between using 'the' vs. 'a' has to do with one specific feeling vs. an unspecified set of feelings. There is a subtle difference in saying "I got a" vs. "I have a", and from what I've seen, it usually has to do with how educated you are (and to clarify, I don't mean English language learners, I mean Native Speakers Who Should Know Better.)

Comment: Notice how "I have a bad feeling about this" is natural but "I have the bad feeling about this" is not .. this is because the speaker is unsure of what that feeling is, and can only express it as "a bad feeling," as an unspecified set (is it fear, disgust, or perhaps it's dread?)

Comment: @Ming You are right when you say someone might say "I have a feeling..." but using the article "the" would not work unless you were saying "I have the feeling of...(falling,etc)" Whether the speaker wants to say they have a feeling, or the feeling is just coming to them (get) would determine if they would use "get" "have" or "have got".

Comment: @tao Agreed, having the feeling and the feeling just emerging are different, where you would want to choose between "have" and "get". My issue was with "I got" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually Chinese people say `我觉得` or `我感觉`, meaning "I feel":

- 我觉得你的英语比我的中文好。
- 我觉得今晚一定会很棒。
- 我感觉他们会否决我的提议。

Or you can use the structurally similar `我有一种感觉`. It sounds more lyrical, and is less commonly seen:

- 我有一种感觉，那就是今晚一定会很棒。
- 我有一种感觉，如果我你逃课的话，老师发现会很生气的。

--

"I got a bad feeling about this" is a different thing. If the thing has not happened, then it's usually "我有一种不祥的预感" or "感觉不妙啊". Most Star Wars references could be translated this way.